# GNUplot print output tom AWK

Tags: awk

This line finds the line in a text file and prints the selected items but how do I insert text into the print output?

```
system("/usr/bin/awk '/-1.98/{print $2 $1}' /pathto/myfile.txt")
```

For example:

```
system("/usr/bin/awk '/-1.98/{print "Items " $2 " and " $1}' /pathto/myfile.txt")
```

Anything like that second line constantly throws up a demand for a parenthesis. Have tried the concatenation operator and commas to no avail.

Comment: It has nothing to do with GNUPlot. BTW just escape the quotes like `\"`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now, how do I pass in a GNUplot variable (let's call it 'lowValue') in place of the -1.98 in that command, so awk searches for the value of the variable?

Comment: Why don't you do something like `system("/usr/bin/awk '/"$variablename"/{print \"Items \" $2 \" and \" $1}' /pathto/myfile.txt")`

Comment: That throws  " ')' expected " with the carat positioned under the $ (which isn't always a useful indicator

Comment: That's just an example. You should replace $variablename by the name you have. You did not specify which language you are programming in.

Comment: Of course I substituted my own variable name - sorry I didn't make that clear! I'm doing this in GNUplot scripts, using GNUplot system() to call awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use printf:

```
system("/usr/bin/awk '/-1.98/{printf "%-s\n", "Items " $2 " and " $1}' /pathto/myfile.txt")
```

It works for:

```
system("/usr/bin/awk '/-1.98/{print "Items " $2 " and " $1}' /pathto/myfile.txt")
```

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/ivQ4sQ